# Using node js, how to add additional details/custom events into requests table in QnA maker App Insights

Tags: node.js, azure-application-insights, azure-qna-maker, kusto-explorer

Using node js, how to add additional details/custom events into requests table in QnA maker App Insights of chatbot. Can these custom events be added either from code using Node. js or directly from Azure QnA Maker application insights?

Comment: Does anyone have any solutions for my above question?

Comment: Does anyone have any suggestions for the above question?